# MySQL procedure fetching data from prepared statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

here is what I want to do:

- Write a MySQL Procedure that:
- gets an array of names (as String) as an Parameter
- Than I want to find all IDs corresponding to those names of one table
- Create for each ID a row in an n:m table with my user ID

I have the following tables:

```
user: ID, username, ....
role: ID, name, description
user_has_role: user_id, role_id
```

I am that far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addUser` (i_username VARCHAR(45), i_hasRoleArray VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE local_sql TEXT;

    SET local_sql = CONCAT ('SELECT id FROM role WHERE name IN (', i_hasRoleArray, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM local_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCALTE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

So I've got the IDs but how to access them now to put them into an INSERT Query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: sounds like something that can be done in a single query. How about posting your real tables and some sample

Comment: There is no way to capture statement output in MySQL. You may try insert select into temporary table in prepared statement and then select from it after DEALLOCATE.

Comment: Yep, an `insert ... select ...` will do the trick.